# Heroku's Jekyll 1033 URL character limit

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

Why does Heroku limit Ruby Jekyll GET URL lengths? Running the Jekyll server locally, I do *not* encounter this issue.

I am seeing a status 414 with a total character count of 1033:

[Twilio GET 414](http://frank.lovecch.io/scripts/door.xml?test=vcwpjbiowaqrbihtqrolwrsardahcmeqaazzufqycuplswhnyowmreupqutysnnluijkldugviqfacajdjetnbcdxvwrjfsemolzgpseedpgphcuhycwkbcluncvvxbdasiuednmtxccnaqfyzcvplhdinrcwmjqftqweyjrpneqhpzfdyvjfubrubbdfpehvuqbuqkmyeeovqqyuussflqnuqxdazdrkshqxdxohswpvsbrjwuffaehjzenujbmejknamnmguovjzhcuyychhdikwblaoripoxgdamxmbcqbvekxxpfvmpuowxwhtqkxvvsfbromyklywgfazovuxjuwordgghdvkuxgqqmhbwwpwmnyotussxolozcglfgnokrsgvtqopdbklawkxhgwhvreeoxxibbxpfpfsembkxxsacyodhywntelobbxayuzsraysnucvegvpzhaazlhlhfhcrskszbxblcjyxubrneapymmfjmigprjuzmhnrpxlmhcchnimdefgqhaxxewhigdquzelfzopqzifhooiyevoqtirympscapfeiqltdvdbghgddgouvlivujofssksepbcxqgnviltujbdbvfuzltxkdpclyrnwxkycmzekhnnlgvbsxtmbaasuvxvgfpzkovyncnxcjbvbzcrbnnwihhrlowpxjgvmiryrvhsnycjhthovvttnnkaegxokgovaejqaghzduznsrouukbwjymgvloeqcembtygqbqqsbmfbfbjmyzmhrvvchfrrtlggdbvefxmaoxojpuczikhgqjngopboehwrqhxkiiwoqvsdotdrrtqxixwnplyjkkfgbvahbujwkgsvczvxpleoglodbshgoagjqdhzusiubfcjwosnvkqkpgikizgxarymmbjslcuhahlkmzsnlrfamjadzdhzwljjsclgbcbaufktihfljajqkpnamrwwgdoxyz)

And a status of 200 with a total character count of 1032:

[Twilio GET 200](http://frank.lovecch.io/scripts/door.xml?test=vcwpjbiowaqrbihtqrolwrsardahcmeqaazzufqycuplswhnyowmreupqutysnnluijkldugviqfacajdjetnbcdxvwrjfsemolzgpseedpgphcuhycwkbcluncvvxbdasiuednmtxccnaqfyzcvplhdinrcwmjqftqweyjrpneqhpzfdyvjfubrubbdfpehvuqbuqkmyeeovqqyuussflqnuqxdazdrkshqxdxohswpvsbrjwuffaehjzenujbmejknamnmguovjzhcuyychhdikwblaoripoxgdamxmbcqbvekxxpfvmpuowxwhtqkxvvsfbromyklywgfazovuxjuwordgghdvkuxgqqmhbwwpwmnyotussxolozcglfgnokrsgvtqopdbklawkxhgwhvreeoxxibbxpfpfsembkxxsacyodhywntelobbxayuzsraysnucvegvpzhaazlhlhfhcrskszbxblcjyxubrneapymmfjmigprjuzmhnrpxlmhcchnimdefgqhaxxewhigdquzelfzopqzifhooiyevoqtirympscapfeiqltdvdbghgddgouvlivujofssksepbcxqgnviltujbdbvfuzltxkdpclyrnwxkycmzekhnnlgvbsxtmbaasuvxvgfpzkovyncnxcjbvbzcrbnnwihhrlowpxjgvmiryrvhsnycjhthovvttnnkaegxokgovaejqaghzduznsrouukbwjymgvloeqcembtygqbqqsbmfbfbjmyzmhrvvchfrrtlggdbvefxmaoxojpuczikhgqjngopboehwrqhxkiiwoqvsdotdrrtqxixwnplyjkkfgbvahbujwkgsvczvxpleoglodbshgoagjqdhzusiubfcjwosnvkqkpgikizgxarymmbjslcuhahlkmzsnlrfamjadzdhzwljjsclgbcbaufktihfljajqkpnamrwwgdoxy)

These long URLs work with Node.js and Play 2.0 applications on Heroku (the types I was able to test quickly with).

This is what is being served to the request: http://http-status.heroku.com/414, but I did not see any documentation on their [Heroku-specific error page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes) for this limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the configuration of a number of things.. routers, other servers, etc.

While there's no hard and fast length limit to the URL, there are a number of systems/tools/browsers that simply stop processing at a certain point:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Compatibility_issues

Comment: I was hoping for Heroku to respond with some limitation on their end; since it works locally and on AWS, I assume it is specific to them.

Comment: They just made some changes to their routing/proxy layer in the last week or so - allowing PATCH for example - so this may have changed.

Comment: Those changes they pushed fixed the error. I'll give you credit for the tip :)